# XML/XSL if else substring

Tags: xml, if-statement, variables, xslt, substring

i would like to substring a variable in **XML/XSL** with an if clause, if the entry is too long.

I tried something like this, but it isn't working like that.

```
                    <xsl:variable id="newId" select="./newId"/>
                    <xsl:template match="newId">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="string-length() &lt; 15">
                                <xsl:value-of select="newId"/>  
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,15)" />
                                 <br>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,16)" />
                                 </br>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: *"isn't working like that"* is not a good description of a problem Please post a [MCVE] showing an example input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be changed in your code.

- xsl:variable has a 'name' attribute, not 'id'
- string-length function needs an argument

Here's how I would do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:variable name="newId" select="'SomeText123456789'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($newId) &lt; 15">
                <xsl:value-of select="$newId"/>  
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:value-of select="substring($newId,1,15)" />
                 <br>
                 <xsl:value-of select="substring($newId,16)" />
                 </br>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjind

Comment: *"string-length function needs an argument"* Not really: If the argument is omitted, it defaults to a node-set with the context node as its only member. https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions

Comment: This one worked quite well, but i exchanged the match with newId and placed the variable with <xsl:variable name="reportId" select="."/> at the first place into the template. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your template except that:

```
<xsl:value-of select="newId"/>
```

needs to be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

since you are already in the context of `newId`.

Don't see why you need the variable if you're not using it - or at all. If you do need it for some reason, then define it properly; what you have now will produce an error.